# Django OperationalError: table sampleapp_userprofile has no column named email

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

[Git Repo](https://github.com/brijesh-kalkani/Login-API-WITH-JWT)

I'm a beginner in the Django. I tried to implement JWT inside Python but when I add a new user I get an error, which is as follows.

> **django.db.utils.OperationalError: table sampleapp_userprofile has no column named email**

I have created the email field and also put the default value in the email field, and I still get this error .. I have provided the git repository and given some code below, please help.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
# Create your models here.

class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, username, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a username')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            password=password,
            username=username,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class UserProfile(AbstractBaseUser):
    email                   = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email",max_length=60, unique=True,default='')
    username                = models.CharField(max_length=30,default='Null')
    password                = models.CharField(verbose_name='password',max_length=16)
    last_login              = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)



    objects = MyAccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    EmailField = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status, generics
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView
from .serializers import *
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view

# Create your views here.

class LoginView(TokenObtainPairView):
    """
    Login View with jWt token authentication
    """
    serializer_class = MyTokenObtainPairSerializer


class registrationView(APIView):

    def post(self,request,format=None):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            serializer = RegistrationSerializer(data=request.data)
            data = {}
            if serializer.is_valid():
                account = serializer.save()
                data['response'] = 'successfully registered new user.'
            else:
                data = serializer.errors
            return Response(data)
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers, status
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from .models import UserProfile

from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView



class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    def validate(self, attrs):
        print('in')
        user = authenticate(username=attrs['username'], password=attrs['password'])
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                data = super().validate(attrs)
                refresh = self.get_token(self.user)
                refresh['username'] = self.user.username
                try:
                    obj = UserProfile.objects.get(user=self.user)
                    refresh['employeeRole'] = obj.employeeRole
                    data["refresh"] = str(refresh)
                    data["access"] = str(refresh.access_token)
                    data["employee_id"] = self.user.id
                    data['user_name']= self.user.username
                    data["employeeRole"] = obj.employeeRole
                    data['first_name']= self.user.first_name
                    data['last_name']= self.user.last_name
                except Exception as e:
                    raise serializers.ValidationError('Something Wrong!')
                return data
            else:
                raise serializers.ValidationError('Account is Blocked')
        else:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Incorrect userid/email and password combination!')


class RegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    email           = serializers.EmailField(style={'input_type': 'email'})
    username        = serializers.CharField(min_length=1)


    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['email','username', 'password']
        extra_kwargs = {
                'password': {'write_only': True,'min_length':8},
        }


    def save(self):

        account = UserProfile(
                    email=self.validated_data['email'],
                    username=self.validated_data['username'],
                    password=self.validated_data['password']
                )
        account.save()
        return account
```

Comment: Hi have you ran ./manage.py makemigrations and ./manage.py migrate

Comment: @tomgalpin Yes, I've done that